# using dialog/post and LINK not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am posting to the dialog/feed URI (using the below URL) and it did work at one time, but now only a blank screen is returned with no errors.  If I remove the LINK parameter, it works.

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=447426138713392&display=popup&caption=Click%20to%20see%20my%20file&link=https%3A//db.tt/mR7hnEfE&redirect_uri=http%3A//www.facebook.com

Comment: It appears some domains are filtered out (in this case dropbox.com and its short domain db.tt). Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: If I change the link domain from db.tt to db.tt.com it allows the link, but obviously doesn't work since it's not where I really want to go.